# heatmap of specific sequence motifs in aligned fasta files

Tags: r, sequence-alignment, heatmap, motifs

I have a collection of fasta files, each containing three aligned sequences. I am interested in understanding the distribution of a specific sequence motif PGP, RGP and KGP in all the alignments. I was wondering if there is possible way in R to create a heatmap highlighting the location of these motifs.

I have tried the code in this [post](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/13414/how-can-i-plot-multiple-sequence-alignment-in-r-as-a-heatmap) to create a heatmap but it is not working as expected. One issue is that ggmsa does not import the fasta file. The fasta file has to be copied into the installation directory for it to work. I have close to 50 aligned files, so not very efficient. The other major problem is it creates a heatmap compared to a reference sequence and not the motifs. Can't figure how to change this.

Any help is much appreciated. Two fasta files containing aligned sequence are as follows,

```
>chain A CO1A1_HUMAN/1-1464 Collagen alpha-1(I) chain
MFSFVDLRLLLLLAATALLTHGQEEGQVEGQDEDIPPITCVQNGLRYHDRDVWKPEPCRICVCDNGKVLCDDVICDETKNCPGAEVPEGECCPVCPDGSESPTDQETTGVEGPKGDTGPRGPRGPAGPPGRDGIPGQPGLPGPPGPPGPPGPPGLGGNFAPQLSYGYDEKSTGGISVPGPMGPSGPRGLPGPPGAPGPQGFQGPPGEPGEPGASGPMGPRGPPGPPGKNGDDGEAGKPGRPGERGPPGPQGARGLPGTAGLPGMKGHRGFSGLDGAKGDAGPAGPKGEPGSPGENGAPGQMGPRGLPGERGRPGAPGPAGARGNDGATGAAGPPGPTGPAGPPGFPGAVGAKGEAGPQGPRGSEGPQGVRGEPGPPGPAGAAGPAGNPGADGQPGAKGANGAPGIAGAPGFPGARGPSGPQGPGGPPGPKGNSGEPGAPGSKGDTGAKGEPGPVGVQGPPGPAGEEGKRGARGEPGPTGLPGPPGERGGPGSRGFPGADGVAGPKGPAGERGSPGPAGPKGSPGEAGRPGEAGLPGAKGLTGSPGSPGPDGKTGPPGPAGQDGRPGPPGPPGARGQAGVMGFPGPKGAAGEPGKAGERGVPGPPGAVGPAGKDGEAGAQGPPGPAGPAGERGEQGPAGSPGFQGLPGPAGPPGEAGKPGEQGVPGDLGAPGPSGARGERGFPGERGVQGPPGPAGPRGANGAPGNDGAKGDAGAPGAPGSQGAPGLQGMPGERGAAGLPGPKGDRGDAGPKGADGSPGKDGVRGLTGPIGPPGPAGAPGDKGESGPSGPAGPTGARGAPGDRGEPGPPGPAGFAGPPGADGQPGAKGEPGDAGAKGDAGPPGPAGPAGPPGPIGNVGAPGAKGARGSAGPPGATGFPGAAGRVGPPGPSGNAGPPGPPGPAGKEGGKGPRGETGPAGRPGEVGPPGPPGPAGEKGSPGADGPAGAPGTPGPQGIAGQRGVVGLPGQRGERGFPGLPGPSGEPGKQGPSGASGERGPPGPMGPPGLAGPPGESGREGAPGAEGSPGRDGSPGAKGDRGETGPAGPPGAPGAPGAPGPVGPAGKSGDRGETGPAGPAGPVGPVGARGPAGPQGPRGDKGETGEQGDRGIKGHRGFSGLQGPPGPPGSPGEQGPSGASGPAGPRGPPGSAGAPGKDGLNGLPGPIGPPGPRGRTGDAGPVGPPGPPGPPGPPGPPSAGFDFSFLPQPPQEKAHDGGRYYRADDANVVRDRDLEVDTTLKSLSQQIENIRSPEGSRKNPARTCRDLKMCHSDWKSGEYWIDPNQGCNLDAIKVFCNMETGETCVYPTQPSVAQKNWYISKNPKDKRHVWFGESMTDGFQFEYGGQGSDPADVAIQLTFLRLMSTEASQNITYHCKNSVAYMDQQTGNLKKALLLQGSNEIEIRAEGNSRFTYSVTVDGCTSHTGAWGKTVIEYKTTKTSRLPIIDVAPLDVGAPDQEFGFDVGPVCFL
>chain B CO1A1_HUMAN/1-1464 Collagen alpha-1(I) chain
MFSFVDLRLLLLLAATALLTHGQEEGQVEGQDEDIPPITCVQNGLRYHDRDVWKPEPCRICVCDNGKVLCDDVICDETKNCPGAEVPEGECCPVCPDGSESPTDQETTGVEGPKGDTGPRGPRGPAGPPGRDGIPGQPGLPGPPGPPGPPGPPGLGGNFAPQLSYGYDEKSTGGISVPGPMGPSGPRGLPGPPGAPGPQGFQGPPGEPGEPGASGPMGPRGPPGPPGKNGDDGEAGKPGRPGERGPPGPQGARGLPGTAGLPGMKGHRGFSGLDGAKGDAGPAGPKGEPGSPGENGAPGQMGPRGLPGERGRPGAPGPAGARGNDGATGAAGPPGPTGPAGPPGFPGAVGAKGEAGPQGPRGSEGPQGVRGEPGPPGPAGAAGPAGNPGADGQPGAKGANGAPGIAGAPGFPGARGPSGPQGPGGPPGPKGNSGEPGAPGSKGDTGAKGEPGPVGVQGPPGPAGEEGKRGARGEPGPTGLPGPPGERGGPGSRGFPGADGVAGPKGPAGERGSPGPAGPKGSPGEAGRPGEAGLPGAKGLTGSPGSPGPDGKTGPPGPAGQDGRPGPPGPPGARGQAGVMGFPGPKGAAGEPGKAGERGVPGPPGAVGPAGKDGEAGAQGPPGPAGPAGERGEQGPAGSPGFQGLPGPAGPPGEAGKPGEQGVPGDLGAPGPSGARGERGFPGERGVQGPPGPAGPRGANGAPGNDGAKGDAGAPGAPGSQGAPGLQGMPGERGAAGLPGPKGDRGDAGPKGADGSPGKDGVRGLTGPIGPPGPAGAPGDKGESGPSGPAGPTGARGAPGDRGEPGPPGPAGFAGPPGADGQPGAKGEPGDAGAKGDAGPPGPAGPAGPPGPIGNVGAPGAKGARGSAGPPGATGFPGAAGRVGPPGPSGNAGPPGPPGPAGKEGGKGPRGETGPAGRPGEVGPPGPPGPAGEKGSPGADGPAGAPGTPGPQGIAGQRGVVGLPGQRGERGFPGLPGPSGEPGKQGPSGASGERGPPGPMGPPGLAGPPGESGREGAPGAEGSPGRDGSPGAKGDRGETGPAGPPGAPGAPGAPGPVGPAGKSGDRGETGPAGPAGPVGPVGARGPAGPQGPRGDKGETGEQGDRGIKGHRGFSGLQGPPGPPGSPGEQGPSGASGPAGPRGPPGSAGAPGKDGLNGLPGPIGPPGPRGRTGDAGPVGPPGPPGPPGPPGPPSAGFDFSFLPQPPQEKAHDGGRYYRADDANVVRDRDLEVDTTLKSLSQQIENIRSPEGSRKNPARTCRDLKMCHSDWKSGEYWIDPNQGCNLDAIKVFCNMETGETCVYPTQPSVAQKNWYISKNPKDKRHVWFGESMTDGFQFEYGGQGSDPADVAIQLTFLRLMSTEASQNITYHCKNSVAYMDQQTGNLKKALLLQGSNEIEIRAEGNSRFTYSVTVDGCTSHTGAWGKTVIEYKTTKTSRLPIIDVAPLDVGAPDQEFGFDVGPVCFL
>chain C CO1A2_HUMAN/1-1366 Collagen alpha-2(I) chain
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------MLSFVDTRTLLLLAVTLCLATCQSLQEETVRKGPAGDRGPRGERGPPGPPGRDGEDGPTGPPGPPGPPGPPGLGGNFAAQYDGKGVGLGPGPMGLMGPRGPPGAAGAPGPQGFQGPAGEPGEPGQTGPAGARGPAGPPGKAGEDGHPGKPGRPGERGVVGPQGARGFPGTPGLPGFKGIRGHNGLDGLKGQPGAPGVKGEPGAPGENGTPGQTGARGLPGERGRVGAPGPAGARGSDGSVGPVGPAGPIGSAGPPGFPGAPGPKGEIGAVGNAGPAGPAGPRGEVGLPGLSGPVGPPGNPGANGLTGAKGAAGLPGVAGAPGLPGPRGIPGPVGAAGATGARGLVGEPGPAGSKGESGNKGEPGSAGPQGPPGPSGEEGKRGPNGEAGSAGPPGPPGLRGSPGSRGLPGADGRAGVMGPPGSRGASGPAGVRGPNGDAGRPGEPGLMGPRGLPGSPGNIGPAGKEGPVGLPGIDGRPGPIGPAGARGEPGNIGFPGPKGPTGDPGKNGDKGHAGLAGARGAPGPDGNNGAQGPPGPQGVQGGKGEQGPPGPPGFQGLPGPSGPAGEVGKPGERGLHGEFGLPGPAGPRGERGPPGESGAAGPTGPIGSRGPSGPPGPDGNKGEPGVVGAVGTAGPSGPSGLPGERGAAGIPGGKGEKGEPGLRGEIGNPGRDGARGAPGAVGAPGPAGATGDRGEAGAAGPAGPAGPRGSPGERGEVGPAGPNGFAGPAGAAGQPGAKGERGAKGPKGENGVVGPTGPVGAAGPAGPNGPPGPAGSRGDGGPPGMTGFPGAAGRTGPPGPSGISGPPGPPGPAGKEGLRGPRGDQGPVGRTGEVGAVGPPGFAGEKGPSGEAGTAGPPGTPGPQGLLGAPGILGLPGSRGERGLPGVAGAVGEPGPLGIAGPPGARGPPGAVGSPGVNGAPGEAGRDGNPGNDGPPGRDGQPGHKGERGYPGNIGPVGAAGAPGPHGPVGPAGKHGNRGETGPSGPVGPAGAVGPRGPSGPQGIRGDKGEPGEKGPRGLPGLKGHNGLQGLPGIAGHHGDQGAPGSVGPAGPRGPAGPSGPAGKDGRTGHPGTVGPAGIRGPQGHQGPAGPPGPPGPPGPPGVSGGGYDFGYDGDFYRADQPRSAPSLRPKDYEVDATLKSLNNQIETLLTPEGSRKNPARTCRDLRLSHPEWSSGYYWIDPNQGCTMDAIKVYCDFSTGETCIRAQPENIPAKNWYRSSKDKKHVWLGETINAGSQFEYNVEGVTSKEMATQLAFMRLLANYASQNITYHCKNSIAYMDEETGNLKKAVILQGSNDVELVAEGNSRFTYTVLVDGCSKKTNEWGKTIIEYKTNKPSRLPFLDIAPLDIGGADQEFFVDIGPVCFK
```

and

```
>chain A CO4A1_HUMAN/1-1669 Collagen alpha-1(IV) chain
---------MGPRLSVWLLLLPAALLLHEEHSRAAA--KGGCAGSGC-GKCDCHGVKGQKGERGLPGLQGVIGFPGMQGPEGPQGPPGQKGDTGEPGLPGTKGTRGPPGASGYPGNPGLPGIPGQDGPPGPPGIPGCNGTKGERGPLGPPGLPGFAGNPGPPGLPGMKGDPGEILGHVPGMLLKGERGFPGIPGTPGPPGLPGLQGPVGPPGFTGPPGPPGPPGPPGEKGQMGLSFQGPKGDKGDQGVSGPPGVPGQA-------QVQEKGDFATKGEKGQKGEPGFQGMPGVGEKGEPGKPGPRGKPGKDGDKGEKGSPGFPGEPGYPGLIGRQGPQGEKGEAGPPGPPGIVIGTGPLGEKGERGYPGTPGPRGEPGPKGFPGLPGQPGPPGLPVPGQAGAPGFPGERGEKGDRGFPGTS-LP-GPSGRDGLPGPPGSPGPPGQPGYTNGIVECQPGPPGDQGPPGIPGQPGFIGEIGEKGQKGESCLICDIDGYRGPPGPQGPPGEIGFPGQPGAKGDRGLPGRDGVAGVPGPQGTPGLIGQPGAKGEPGEFYFDLRLKGDKGDPGFPGQPGMPGRAGSPGRDGHPGLPGPKGSPGSVGLKGERGPPGGVGFPGSRGDTGPPGPPGY---GPAGPIGDKGQAGFPGGPGSPGLPGPKGEPGKIVP--------------------LPGPPGAEGLPGSPGFPGPQGDRGFPGTPGRPGLPGEKGAVGQPGI-GFPGPPGPKGVDGLPGDMGPPGTPGRPGFNGLPGNPGVQGQKGEP---GVGLPGLKGLPGLPGIPGTPGEKGSIGVPGVPGEHGAIGPPGLQGIRGEPGPPGLPGSVGSPGVPGI-GPPGARGPPGGQGPPGLSGPPGIKGEKGFPGFPGLD-MPGPKGDKGAQGLPGITGQSGLPGLPGQQGAPGIPGFPGSKGEMGVMGTPGQPGSPGPVGAPGLPGEKGDHGFPGSSGPRGDPGLKGDKGDVGLPGKPGSMDKVDMGSMKGQKGDQGEKGQIGPIGEKGSRGDPGTPGVPGKDGQAGQPGQP-GPKGDPGISGTPGAPGLPGPKGSVGGMGLPGTPGEKGVPGIPGPQGSPGLPGDKGAKGEKGQAGPPGIGIPGLRGEKGDQGIAGFPGSPGEKGEKGSIGIPGMPGSPGLKGSPGSVGYPGSPGLPGEKGDKGLPGLDGIPGVKGEAGLPGTPGPTGPAGQKGEPGSDGIPGSAGEKGEPGLPGRGFPGFPGAKGDKGSKGEVGFP-GLAGSPGIPGSKGEQGFMGPPGPQGQPGLPGSPGHA-TEGPKGDRGPQGQPGLPGLPGPMGPPGLPGIDGVKGDKGNPGWPGAPGVPGPKGDPGFQGMPGIGGSPGITGSKGDMGPPGVPGFQGPKGLPGLQGIKGDQGDQGVPGAKGLPGPPGPPGPYDIIKGEPGLPGPEGPPGLKGLQGLPGPKGQQGVTGLVGIPGPPGIPGFDGAPGQKGEMGPAGPTGPRGFPGPPGPDGLPGSMGPPGTPSVDHGFLVTRHSQTIDDPQCPSGTKILYHGYSLLYVQGNERAHGQDLGTAGSCLRKFSTMPFLFCNINNVCNFASRNDYSYWLSTPEPMPMSMAPITGENIRPFISRCAVCEAPAMVMAVHSQTIQIPPCPSGWSSLWIGYSFVMHTSAGAEGSGQALASPGSCLEEFRSAPFIECHG-RGTCNYYANAYSFWLATIERSEMFKKPTPSTLKAGELRTHVSRCQVCMRRT
>chain B CO4A1_HUMAN/1-1669 Collagen alpha-1(IV) chain
---------MGPRLSVWLLLLPAALLLHEEHSRAAA--KGGCAGSGC-GKCDCHGVKGQKGERGLPGLQGVIGFPGMQGPEGPQGPPGQKGDTGEPGLPGTKGTRGPPGASGYPGNPGLPGIPGQDGPPGPPGIPGCNGTKGERGPLGPPGLPGFAGNPGPPGLPGMKGDPGEILGHVPGMLLKGERGFPGIPGTPGPPGLPGLQGPVGPPGFTGPPGPPGPPGPPGEKGQMGLSFQGPKGDKGDQGVSGPPGVPGQA-------QVQEKGDFATKGEKGQKGEPGFQGMPGVGEKGEPGKPGPRGKPGKDGDKGEKGSPGFPGEPGYPGLIGRQGPQGEKGEAGPPGPPGIVIGTGPLGEKGERGYPGTPGPRGEPGPKGFPGLPGQPGPPGLPVPGQAGAPGFPGERGEKGDRGFPGTS-LP-GPSGRDGLPGPPGSPGPPGQPGYTNGIVECQPGPPGDQGPPGIPGQPGFIGEIGEKGQKGESCLICDIDGYRGPPGPQGPPGEIGFPGQPGAKGDRGLPGRDGVAGVPGPQGTPGLIGQPGAKGEPGEFYFDLRLKGDKGDPGFPGQPGMPGRAGSPGRDGHPGLPGPKGSPGSVGLKGERGPPGGVGFPGSRGDTGPPGPPGY---GPAGPIGDKGQAGFPGGPGSPGLPGPKGEPGKIVP--------------------LPGPPGAEGLPGSPGFPGPQGDRGFPGTPGRPGLPGEKGAVGQPGI-GFPGPPGPKGVDGLPGDMGPPGTPGRPGFNGLPGNPGVQGQKGEP---GVGLPGLKGLPGLPGIPGTPGEKGSIGVPGVPGEHGAIGPPGLQGIRGEPGPPGLPGSVGSPGVPGI-GPPGARGPPGGQGPPGLSGPPGIKGEKGFPGFPGLD-MPGPKGDKGAQGLPGITGQSGLPGLPGQQGAPGIPGFPGSKGEMGVMGTPGQPGSPGPVGAPGLPGEKGDHGFPGSSGPRGDPGLKGDKGDVGLPGKPGSMDKVDMGSMKGQKGDQGEKGQIGPIGEKGSRGDPGTPGVPGKDGQAGQPGQP-GPKGDPGISGTPGAPGLPGPKGSVGGMGLPGTPGEKGVPGIPGPQGSPGLPGDKGAKGEKGQAGPPGIGIPGLRGEKGDQGIAGFPGSPGEKGEKGSIGIPGMPGSPGLKGSPGSVGYPGSPGLPGEKGDKGLPGLDGIPGVKGEAGLPGTPGPTGPAGQKGEPGSDGIPGSAGEKGEPGLPGRGFPGFPGAKGDKGSKGEVGFP-GLAGSPGIPGSKGEQGFMGPPGPQGQPGLPGSPGHA-TEGPKGDRGPQGQPGLPGLPGPMGPPGLPGIDGVKGDKGNPGWPGAPGVPGPKGDPGFQGMPGIGGSPGITGSKGDMGPPGVPGFQGPKGLPGLQGIKGDQGDQGVPGAKGLPGPPGPPGPYDIIKGEPGLPGPEGPPGLKGLQGLPGPKGQQGVTGLVGIPGPPGIPGFDGAPGQKGEMGPAGPTGPRGFPGPPGPDGLPGSMGPPGTPSVDHGFLVTRHSQTIDDPQCPSGTKILYHGYSLLYVQGNERAHGQDLGTAGSCLRKFSTMPFLFCNINNVCNFASRNDYSYWLSTPEPMPMSMAPITGENIRPFISRCAVCEAPAMVMAVHSQTIQIPPCPSGWSSLWIGYSFVMHTSAGAEGSGQALASPGSCLEEFRSAPFIECHG-RGTCNYYANAYSFWLATIERSEMFKKPTPSTLKAGELRTHVSRCQVCMRRT
>chain C CO4A2_HUMAN/1-1712 Collagen alpha-2(IV) chain
MGRDQRAVAGPALRRWLLLGTVTVGFLAQSVLAGVKKFDVPCGGRDCSGGCQCYPEKGGRGQPGPVGPQGYNGPPGLQGFPGLQGRKGDKGERGAPGVTGPKGDVGARGVSGFPGADGIPGHPGQGGPRGRPGYDGCNGTQGDSGPQGPPGSEGFTGPPGPQGPKGQKGEP-YALPKEERDRYRGEPGEPGLVGFQGPPGRPGHVGQMGPVGAPGRPGPPGPPGPKGQQGNRGLGFYGVKGEKGDVGQPGPNGIPSDTLHPIIAPTGVTFHPDQYKGEKGSEGEPGIRGISLKGEEGIMGFPGLRGYPGLSGEKGSPGQKGSRGLDGYQGPDGPRGPKGEAGDPGPPGLP--AYSPHPSLAKGARGDPGFPGAQGEPGSQGEPGDPGLPGPPGLSIGDGDQRRGLPGEMGPKGFIGDPGIPALYGGPPGPDGKRGPPGPPGLPGPPGPDGFL-FGLKGAKGRAGFPGLPGSPGARGPKGWKGDAGECRCTEGDEAIKGLPGLPGPKGFAGINGEPGRKGDRGDPGQHGLPGFPGLKGVPGNIGAPGPKGAKGDS-RTITTKGERGQPGVPGVPGMKGDDGSPGRDGLDGFPGLPGPPGD-GIKGPPGDPGYPGIPGTKGTPGEMGPPGLGLPGLKGQRGFPGDAGLPGPPGFLGPPGPAGTPGQIDCDTDVKRAVGGDRQEAIQPGCIGGPKGLPGLPGPPGPTGAKGLRGIPGFAGADGGPGPRGLPGDAGREGFPGPPGFIGPRGSKGAVGLPGPDGSPGPIGLPGPDGPPGERGLPGEVLGAQPGPRGDAGVPGQPGLKGLPGDRGPPGFRGSQGMPGMPGLKGQPGLPGPSGQPGLYGPPGLHGFPGAPGQEGPLGLPGIPGREGLPGDRGDPGDTGAPGPVGMKGLSGDRGDAGFTGEQGHPGSPGFKGIDGMPGTPGLKGDRGSPGMDGFQGMPGLKGRPGFPGSKGEAGFFGIPGLKGLAGEPGFKGSRGDPGPPGPP-PVILPGMKDIKGEKGDEGPMGLKGYLGAKGIQGMPGIPGLSGIPGLPGRPGHIKGVKGDIGVPGIPGLPGFPGVAGPPGITGFPGFIGSRGDKGAPGRAGLYGEIGATGDFGDIGDT-INLPGRPGLKGERGTTGIPGLKGFFGEKGTEGDIGFPGITGVTGVQGPPGLKGQTGFPGLTGPPGSQGELGRIGLPGGKGDDGWPGAPGLPGFPGLRGIRGLHGLPGTKGFPGSPGSDIHGDPGFPGPPGERGDPGEANTLPGPVGVPGQKGDQGAPGERGPPGSPGLQGFPGITPPSNISGAPGDKGAPGIFGLKGYRGPPGPPGSAALPGSKGDTGNPGAPGTPGTKGWAGDSGPQGRPGVFGLPGEKGPRGEQGFMGNTGPTGAVGDRGPKGPKGDPGFPGAPGTVGAPGIAGIPQKIAVQPGTVGPQGRRGPPGAPGEMGPQGPPGEPGFRGAPGKAGPQGRGGVSAVPGFRGDEGPIGHQGPIGQEGAPGRPGSPGLPGMPGR-SVSIGYLLVKHSQTDQEPMCPVGMNKLWSGYSLLYFEGQEKAHNQDLGLAGSCLARFSTMPFLYCNPGDVCYYASRNDKSYWLSTTAPLP--MMPVAEDEIKPYISRCSVCEAPAIAIAVHSQDVSIPHCPAGWRSLWIGYSFLMHTAAGDEGGGQSLVSPGSCLEDFRATPFIECNGGRGTCHYYANKYSFWLTTIPEQSFQGSPSADTLKAGLIRTHISRCQVCMKNL
```

Comment: When I want an MSA visualization in R that I can't find pre-made, my approach is to put the text into a data frame of position/character combos and use generic plotting tools like `pheatmap` or ggplot2's `geom_tile`.  Looks like that'd get tricky here because of the gaps and multi-AA motifs though.  Maybe it'd work with a mapping of gapped/ungapped locations of all AA trios instead of individual characters?  And for simple FASTA reading maybe check out this [minimalistic package](https://github.com/sherrillmix/dnar) from a colleague of mine.  It just reads the text into data frames.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution based on Jesse's comment. The steps are:

1. read in MSA with `Biostrings::readAAStringSet()`
2. right-fill sequences so they are all the same length (assumes left alignment)
3. search for motif substrings in each amino acid sequence with `gregexpr()`. If a motif in the motif set is found, record position of center of motif.
4. bind the results from each sequence to a single table

```
find_motifs <- function(msa, motifs) {

  require(tibble)
  require(Biostrings)

  # read in fasta as Biostrings object
  seqs <- Biostrings::readAAStringSet(filepath = msa, format = "fasta")
  maxseqlen <- max(width(seqs))

  # initiate results tibble
  results <- tibble::tibble(position = seq(1:maxseqlen))

  # readAAMultipleAlignment requires equal length of sequences
  # instead, use readAAStringSet and fill "-" on right
  # assumes left-aligned MSA
  for (i in 1:length(seqs)) {
    
    seqlen <- nchar(seqs[i])
    
    if (seqlen < maxseqlen) {
      fill <- maxseqlen - seqlen
      seqs[[i]] <- paste0(as.character(seqs[[i]]),
                          paste(rep("-", fill), collapse = ""))
    }

    # initiate vector of zeros to store hit positions
    positions <- rep(0, maxseqlen)
    
    lapply(motifs, function(motif) {
      
      # factor to add to gregexpr output to center hit
      # for motifs with an even number of characters, use left center
      shift <- ceiling(nchar(motif)/2)
      
      hits <- unlist(gregexpr(motif, seqs[[i]])) + shift
      
      lapply(hits, function(hit) {
        positions[hit] <<- 1
      }) # end apply over hits
    
    }) # end apply over motifs
    
    results <- dplyr::bind_cols(results, positions)
    
  } # end loop over sequences
  
  names(results) <- c("position", paste0("seq", seq(1:length(seqs))))
  results
  
} # end function
```

Running this function on the provided fastas, we get a tables where positions in sequences matching motifs are recorded as `1`.

```
setwd("/path/to/files")
ngp <- c("PGP","RGP","KGP")
msa1 <- find_motifs(msa = "msa1.fasta",
                    motifs = ngp)
msa2 <- find_motifs(msa = "msa2.fasta",
                    motifs = ngp)

dplyr::slice(msa1, 120:130)

# A tibble: 11 × 4
   position  seq1  seq2  seq3
      <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1      120     0     0     0
 2      121     0     0     0
 3      122     1     1     1
 4      123     0     0     0
 5      124     0     0     0
 6      125     1     1     0
 7      126     0     0     0
 8      127     0     0     0
 9      128     0     0     1
10      129     0     0     0
11      130     0     0     0
```

And here's a function to make the plots.

```
heatmap_separate <- function(data) {
  require(ggplot2)
  require(tidyr)
  numseqs <- ncol(data) - 1
  numrows <- nrow(data)
  toplot <- data |> tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -position,
                                        names_to = "sequence",
                                        values_to = "hits")
    ggplot(toplot) +
    geom_tile(mapping = aes(x = position,
                            y = sequence,
                            fill = as.factor(hits),
                            color = as.factor(hits))) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,numrows),
                       n.breaks = 10,
                       expand = c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = rev) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#f2f0f7","#54278f")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#f2f0f7","#54278f")) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5 + 0:numseqs,
               color = "black",
               linewidth = 1.5) + 
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          panel.grid = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = "black"),
          panel.background = element_blank())
}

heatmap_separate(msa1)
heatmap_separate(msa2)
```

##### Plot for fasta #1

[image]

##### Plot for fasta #2

[image]

The lines representing hits are all plotted as the same color (`#54278f`), but they appear to be different colors as an artifact of plotting lots of narrow tiles. This can be rectified by viewing the plots as svg files, though I can't display that file type here.